# Transform specific column values and replace it with mean value

Tags: python, pandas

I started off to filter the house data with column 'bedrooms', 'bathrooms', and 'sqft_lot' with specific values i.e. 0 bedrooms, 0.5 bathrooms, & sqft >= 2000. Because I think the square feet values are off if there are only this little bedroom and bathrooms.

Here is my first code:

```py
house[(house['bedrooms']==0) & (house['bathrooms']== 0.50) & (house['sqft_lot']>= 2000)]
```

[image: Code 1 Data]

Second code, trying to get an overview of aggregate functions:

```py
house[(house['bedrooms']==0) & (house['bathrooms']== 0.50) & (house['sqft_lot']>= 2000)].describe()
```

[image: Code 2 Data]

Third code, trying to replace the mean value from code 2 to code 1, but running into an error:

```py
house[(house['bedrooms']==0) & (house['bathrooms']== 0.50) & (house['sqft_lot']>= 2000)].transform('mean'), inplace=True
```

```
File "<ipython-input-68-a4d1302fafe8>", line 1
        house[(house['bedrooms']==0) & (house['bathrooms']== 0.50) & (house['sqft_lot']>= 2000)].transform('mean'), inplace=True
                                                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Does anyone has any ideas as to how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi @Laurent, I'm trying to replace the mean value on the columns/values I specified and overwrite the original dataset, which is why I put inplace=True, or does it not work in this case?

Comment: Right, but my point is that `inplace=True` should appear inside a method call: `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` for instance, not outside on is own: `df.rest_index(), inplace=True`. So, this is either a mistake or the code you posted is incomplete. Cheers.

Comment: @laurent I think you made a good point, I will check the code again. Thanks!